# Run SpringLiquibase BEFORE Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liquibase

I'm using SpringLiquibase to apply my liquibase update automatically during the application startup. In general this works fine, but when I set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to "validate" then hibernate starts to complain about the database scheme before liquibase seems to have the chance to apply the updates.
My configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:myapp.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myapp")
public class MyappConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase/liquibase-master-changelog.xml");
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        String[] propertyNames = new String[]{"hibernate.dialect", "hibernate.show_sql", "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"};

        for (String propertyName : propertyNames) {
            properties.put(propertyName, env.getRequiredProperty(propertyName));
        }
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to get liquibase to apply its updates BEFORE hibernate tries to validate the schema?

Comment: You might try adding a `@DependsOn("liquibase")` to your `entityManagerFactory` bean definition.

Comment: How can i do the thing with `@DependsOn("liquibase") ` if I have the beans declared in `applicationContext.xml` ?

Comment: @MoroianuAlexandru you can move the config of liquibase to applicationContext.xml too

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum & VinhNT I solved it by applying depends-on in applicationContext.xml... defined following code in xml: `<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="liquibase">` [...]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to  [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) I was able to solve this by using

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("liquibase")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
   [...]
}
```

The `@DependsOn` makes sure that liquibase is run before Hibernates schema validation.

Comment: How do I do this in Spring-Boot using Spring-JPA? When I do mvn install, liquibase is getting executed first. But when I start application, hibernate ddl is run first.