# Execute Liquibase before hibernate in SPRINGBOOT using SpringJPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I am working on already existing project which uses `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`. I am adding new table using `liquibase`.

When I do `mvn install`, migrations are being applied correctly and when I do a `java -jar target/MyApplication.java` Schema Update happens `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update`.

I don't understand why this behaviour is, can somebody help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: When you are using Liquibase (or any other DB evolution tool) you shouldn't use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` but use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` instead. This will make Hibernate not to apply any changes, and delegate this task to Liquibase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run SpringLiquibase BEFORE Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677656/run-springliquibase-before-hibernate)