# Incorrect db migration

Tags: spring, migration, liquibase

I try to set up Liquibase as java bean in Spring persistence config, set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate ,  but after all it falls with

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ru.rambler.alexeimohov.spring.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [address]

If i set hbm2ddl.auto=update Hibernate builds all tables and Liquibase builds DATABASECHANGELOG
and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK .I tried to use @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) on Liquibase bean with no success.

Having for test purpose only one table inside db.init_1.0.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <changeSet author="author" id="1">
              <createTable tableName="address"
                     schemaName="first">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: BTW I am pretty sure there is no any issues with wrong classpath or something.

Answer (score 0):

@DependsOn annotations fixed my problem.

Comment: Where You have added it?

Comment: Unfortunately, have already deleted the code. I guess it was placed on EntityManagerFactory, making him dependent on Liquibase bean. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677656/run-springliquibase-before-hibernate

Comment: Thank You very much